# Replicate Power BI report and dataset to multile workspaces on Power BI Service

Tags: powerbi

I have a report and a dataset in Power BI service WorkspaceA. I would like to replicate this report and dataset to WorkspaceB, WorkspaceC and WorkspaceD.
Is it possible without using a Deployment Pipeline (and having to change the target workspace everytime)?
Is it possible without publishing this report from Power BI Desktop to all four desired workspaces one by one?
Thank you

Comment: Just curious, but why not have the dataset in one workspace, and reports built upon that dataset for the other workspaces. From a maintenance perspective, this is much simpler. You only need to refresh the dataset once, and in one place.

Comment: Hello Zach, each dataset will be pointing to a different database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could utilize powershell for the deployment of your datasets/reports. Some scripts can be found [here](https://github.com/microsoft/PowerBI-Developer-Samples/tree/master/PowerShell%20Scripts) from microsoft.